# can I bind hotkey for zsh?

Tags: zsh

I want to bind `<C-h>` to execute `tmux slect-window -t -1`, `<C-l>` to execute `tmux slect-window -t +1` in zsh, can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by adding a couple of zsh functions, registering them as `zle` widgets, and then use `bindkey` to map them to hotkeys.

I wouldn't want to bind anything to `<C-l>` though, since that's usually the keybinding for `clear`, and I use that quite a lot.

This should solve your problem:

```
control_h() {
  tmux select-window -t -1
}
zle -N control_h
bindkey "\Ch" control_h

control_l() {
  tmux select-window -t +1
}
zle -N control_l
bindkey "\Cl" control_l
```

How to create basic keyboard shortcuts in zsh is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836572/to-make-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-info-in-zsh)